# How to know if a cell has an image in its image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a table view that contain cells... some have images and some do not. I would like to size the cells that have images larger than those that don't.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 150;

}
```

With this code, how would I tell if indexPath has an image or not? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same logic that you use in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to obtain the model information that is backing the `UITableViewCell`.

Now you have the info that populates the `UITableViewCell` you can query if you provided an image.